# Performance vs weather Regression analysis

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, weather, pearson-correlation

I am pretty new to statistics and tring to get my head around what is the best way and how to analyse the performance data against weather data.

My hypothesis is that the performance data is affected by the weather data and I want to prove that.

I tried to plot the daily performance data & meantemp data on a scatterplot to do regression analysis and it looks odd. I think this is due to negative values in weather data.

[image: Scatter plot]

Below are all the weather information that is available to me:
fog,    rain,   snow,   hail,   thunder,    tornado,    meantempm,  meantempi,  meandewptm, meandewpti, meanpressurem,  meanpressurei,  meanwindspdm,   meanwindspdi,   meanwdird,  meanvism,   meanvisi,   humidity,   maxtempm,   maxtempi,   mintempm,   mintempi,   maxhumidity,    minhumidity,    maxdewptm,  maxdewpti,  mindewptm,  mindewpti,  maxpressurem,   maxpressurei,   minpressurem,   minpressurei,   maxwspdm,   maxwspdi,   minwspdm,   minwspdi,   maxvism,    maxvisi,    minvism,    minvisi,    gdegreedays,    heatingdegreedays,  coolingdegreedays

Could you advise me on what is the best way to analyse this data and get some meaningful result please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a linear regression on the data plotted in your question you should get a slope of nearly zero, meaning there is no linear relationship in the data.  So one somewhat simple approach is to make a linear regression of all available data, looking for any slope other than zero (either positive or negative).  There are better statistical techniques for sure, however this can be informative and is easily automated.

Comment: Thanks James, what other statistical techniques would you recommend? I am mostly interested in temperature so if the current data doesn't show anything I think the hypothesis is not correct.

Comment: The presence of rain and the presence of thunder are not independent of one another.  I have done some work in multiple regression, where multiple independent variables are regressed against a single dependent variable, but nothing with this degree of complex interdependence.  If you perform a multiple regression against all variables, my intuition is that the resulting covariance matrix would show most of the factors have a relatively large covariance - that is, they do not vary independently of one another.  It is worth doing for the sake of completeness and statistical certainty.